# Raspberry bleno disconnects when lightblue application connect secure charactheristic

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi4, bluez, bleno

I'm doing some tests with bleno installed on a Raspberry Pi, and i'm experiencing big issues with secure characteristics.

I can replicate this scenario with LightBlue on android and iPhone.

If i define a service with a secure charachteristic, when i try to read this charachteristic, bleno fires the disconnect callback, and it freezes until i restart it.

I've already upgraded to bluez 5.64, nothing changed.

```
 var StaticReadOnlyCharacteristic = function() {
  StaticReadOnlyCharacteristic.super_.call(this, {
    uuid: 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1',
    properties: ['read'],
    secure:['read'],
    value: Buffer.from('value'),
    descriptors: [
      new BlenoDescriptor({
        uuid: '2901',
        value: 'user description'
      })
    ]
  });
};
util.inherits(StaticReadOnlyCharacteristic, BlenoCharacteristic);

function SampleService() {
  SampleService.super_.call(this, {
    uuid: 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0',
    characteristics: [
      new StaticReadOnlyCharacteristic()
    ]
  });
}

util.inherits(SampleService, BlenoPrimaryService);

bleno.on('stateChange', function(state) {
  console.log('on -> stateChange: ' + state + ', address = ' + bleno.address);

  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    bleno.startAdvertising('test', ['fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0']);
  } else {
    bleno.stopAdvertising();
  }
});
```

Comment: bleno is not maintained anymore…would not use it

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie when I up service "hciconfig hci0" then connect and display services, but after some time, he is an auto disconnect in light blue application.